# Problem with creating labels from .csv -file

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I’m trying to do a face detection model with jupyter Notebook and encountering some difficulties when trying to write a .csv file with the file names and labels.

Here are the functions I use:

```
##Attaching label to correct file names

item_list = glob.glob('data/dest/celeba/faces/*/*.jpg'.  )

item_df = pd.DataFrame({'image_name':pd.Series(item_list).apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.split('/')[-2]))})

istem_df['image_id'] = item_df.image_name.apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[1])


## Creating final label set


label_df = pd.read_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels.csv')

label_df = label_df.merge(item_df, on='image_id', how='inner')

label_df.rename(columns={'label':'tags'}, inplace=True)

label_df.loc[:,['image_name','tags']].to_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels1.csv', index=False)
```

So the “labels.csv” is like it should be, I think. Here’s a couple of lines from the start of the file:

```
,image_id,label
0,000001.jpg,Arched_Eyebrows Attractive Brown_Hair Heavy_Makeup High_Cheekbones Mouth_Slightly_Open No_Beard Pointy_Nose Smiling Straight_Hair Wearing_Earrings Wearing_Lipstick Young
1,000002.jpg,Bags_Under_Eyes Big_Nose Brown_Hair High_Cheekbones Mouth_Slightly_Open No_Beard Smiling Young
```

This should be written again with “tags”. But the labels1.csv looks like this:

```
image_name,tags
```

Otherwise it’s empty. When I call `print(data.c,'\n',data.classes)`, it prints `0 []`.

Can anyone help me to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Edit. I'm editing this to here to avoid chatting. So I've edited my code according to the help I've recieved and this is what it looks like now:

```
## Attachhing label to correct file names
item_list = glob.glob('data/dest/celeba/faces/*/*.jpg')
item_df = pd.DataFrame({'image_name':pd.Series(item_list).apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.split('/')[-2]))})
item_df['image_id'] = item_df.image_name.apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[1])

## Creating final label set
label_df = pd.read_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels.csv')
label_df = label_df.merge(item_df, left_on='image_id', right_on='image_id')
label_df.rename(columns={'label':'tags'}, inplace=True)
label_df.loc[:,['image_name','tags']].to_csv('data/dest/celeba/faces/labels.csv', index=False)
```

This still gives me an empty "labels1.csv" -file with just the headers: `image_name,tags`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using.loc method to get only ['image_name','tags'] from row ids.
Change this part:

```py
label_df.loc[:,['image_name','tags']].to_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels1.csv', index=False)
```

with this:

```py
header = ["image_id", "tags"]
label_df.to_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels1.csv', columns = header, index=False)
```

Comment: The `labels1.csv` is still empty. I think the problem is this line: `label_df = label_df.merge(item_df, on='image_id', how='inner')`, after that the tag is renamed, but the csv is otherwise empty. I try to create my dataBunch with this: `tfms = get_transforms(do_flip=False, flip_vert=False, max_rotate=30, max_lighting=0.3)` `src = (ImageItemList.from_csv(path, csv_name='labels.csv')
       .split_by_valid_func(validation_func)
       .label_from_df(cols='tags',label_delim=' '))`

`data = (src.transform(tfms, size=128)
       .databunch(bs=256).normalize(imagenet_stats))`

Comment: Which is your problem? Wrong headers or no data in csv. I couldn't understand the issue from your questions.

Comment: The problem is no data in csv. In my question I described what "labels.csv" and "labels1.csv" should contain. The "labels.csv" is ok, but I think that data should be copied to the "labels1.csv" and that doesn't work.

Comment: Here are the links to the notebooks I've been folowing: Data Prepration: https://github.com/aayushmnit/Deep_learning_explorations/blob/master/7_Facial_attributes_fastai_opencv/Data_prepration.ipynb, creating data bunch etc: https://github.com/aayushmnit/Deep_learning_explorations/blob/master/7_Facial_attributes_fastai_opencv/MultiClass%20classification%20on%20CelebA%20dataset%20using%20FastAI.ipynb

Comment: df.loc method will take only the line you required. So, in your code you are getting header line with image_id, label. You want to use this code ```label_df.to_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels1.csv', columns=['image_id', 'tags'] , header = True, index=False)``` for all the data in your dataframe.

Comment: labels1.csv is still empty, just this: `image_id,tags`. I tried this for logging the problem: `label_df = pd.read_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels.csv')
label_df = label_df.merge(item_df, on='image_id', how='inner')
label_df.to_csv('data/dest/celeba/labels1.csv', columns=['image_id', 'tags'] , header = True, index=False)` and it gives the same result: `image_id,tags`, otherwise empty file. So the problem is in merging these two files?

Comment: Exactly you should use ```label_df.merge(item_df , left_on='image_id', right_on='image_id')``` should give a result probably with some empty cells but lets proceed step by step. Do you have ```image_id``` in ```item_df```, it seems that you only have ```image_name``` in ```item_df```.

Comment: I edited my original question, it's more clear than writing comments. I'm not sure what you mean with if I have image_id in item_id, but from my edit you can see there is `image_id` in `item_df`?

Comment: @bodyPar I just edited the answer above. I think your .loc usage is not compatible with what u are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help @furknayad. Still not able to get this right, the destination csv remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to create 2 folders named 'training' and 'validation' inside "data/celeba/faces/".

Some changes in the code :

```
## Attaching label to correct file names
item_list = glob.glob('data/celeba/faces/*/*.jpg')

item_df = pd.DataFrame({'image_name' : pd.Series(item_list).apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.split('/')[-2:]))})
item_df['image_id'] = item_df.image_name.apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[-1])
item_df.head()

## Creating final label set
label_df = pd.read_csv('data/celeba/labels.csv')
label_df = label_df.merge(item_df, on='image_id', how='inner')
label_df.rename(columns={'label':'tags'}, inplace=True)
label_df.loc[:,['image_name','tags']].to_csv('data/celeba/faces/labels.csv', index=False)
```

This will help you create your 'label.csv' by merging dataframes, and split your dataset into training and validation.